# Windows Store verify subscription server-side

Tags: c#, uwp

I want a very simple thing - let user buy a subscription in my `UWP` app and then periodically check that this subscription is still active server side (the app is for multiple platforms, user can buy subscription on any one and use it on all his devices).

On Android, the app receives a purchase receipt which can be used against Google service which returns current state of the subscription.

For Windows Store, it seems ([Manage product entitlements from a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/view-and-grant-products-from-a-service)) I need to:

> 1. Ask my service for Azure access token, pass it to my app
> 2. Generate Store ID in my app
> 3. Pass this ID back to my service
> 4. Use this ID to get a list of all user's subscriptions to verify  their status
> 5. Refresh the Store ID every 3 months (its validity)

I'm counting 5 REST calls just to check a state of my subscription.
Is that really the only way?

There used to be an API to get the receipt from Store, but that seems deprecated now:
[Windows.ApplicationModel.Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.store)

Comment: Hi @Tomáš, did you manage to implement server-side subscription verification? We have a similar simple requirement, but "Get subscriptions for a user" API doesn't work for us — it always returns empty items. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/51968616/1664795

Answer (score 0):

> for 1 year subscription, after the year goes by, I want to ask if the subscription was extended or not.

Please check this document: [Get subscriptions for a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/get-subscriptions-for-a-user).

If your subscription is part of a cross-platform service, you can call this API to determine whether the specified user has an entitlement for your subscription and the status of their subscription in the context of your UWP app. You can then use this information to update the status of the subscription on other platforms that your service supports.

Comment: I know that. My question is not about subscription periods, but about verifying the subscription server-side. E.g. for 1 year subscription, after the year goes by, I want to ask if the subscription was extended or not.

Comment: @TomášBezouška It's ok. I'm so sorry for misunderstanding your question. Please see my updated reply.